# Best way to get list of id's from hashMap values

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a `HashMap` having `Integer` as keys and `List<Employee>` as values. I want to get all `Ids` from all `Values` of `HashMap`

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    hm.forEach((key, value) -> {
        List<Integer> c = value.stream()
                .map(Employee::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        ids.addAll(c);
     }
```

Here is how I am trying to do so far.
Is there a way to directly stream from values of `HashMap` and get all distinct values?

Comment: `hm.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).map(Employee::getId).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Thank you @shmosel this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: btw see [how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

```
hm.values()
      .stream()
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .map(Employee::getId)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Since you are interested in Ids only, stream over `values` of `HashMap`, and since each of those are `List`(s),  you would use `flatMap`, the rest is probably obvious. Also since these are distinct as you say, a return type of `Set` makes a lot more sense.

If you still require a `List` just use:

```
.... .map(Employee::getId)
     .distinct()
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Long> ids = hm.values().stream().map(Employee::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here what we have done is get values as stream and map employee id and collect as list.

Its not needed re add to list.

Comment: Remember that `values()` returns `List<Employee>`, not `Employee`, so your `map` operation does not work here (use `flatMap` instead).